# How do have a class method that redefines other class methods?

Tags: ruby

I want to wrap all class methods for a module with logging, like this:

```
module SomeModule

  def self.foo
    puts "bar"
  end

  class << self
    SomeModule.methods(false).each do |method|
      alias_method "old_#{method}".to_sym, method
      define_method method do |*args|
        puts "Called method: #{method}"
        send "old_#{method}", *args
      end
    end
  end
end

SomeModule.foo
#-> Called method: foo
#-> bar
```

That works perfectly.  But what if I wanted the wrapping to only happen when I called a method?  How could I make this happen when you call

```
module SomeModule
  def self.foo
    puts "bar"
  end

  def self.add_logging_to_all_methods
    #???
  end
end  
SomeModule.add_logging_to_all_methods

SomeModule.foo
#-> Called method: foo
#-> bar
```

Comment: Ooh, actually I did have this working okay... turns out my problem was somewhere else... it always seems to be that way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m not going to ask what you want this for, but here it is:

```
module SomeModule

  def self.foo
    puts "bar"
  end

  def self.add_logging_to_all_methods
    eigenclass = class << self; self; end
    methods(false).each do |method|
      eigenclass.class_eval do
        alias_method "old_#{method}".to_sym, method
        define_method method do |*args|
          puts "Called method: #{method}"
          send "old_#{method}", *args
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
SomeModule.add_logging_to_all_methods

SomeModule.foo
```

Be aware that this also adds “logging” to `add_logging_to_all_methods`, but only after invoking it, so if you only invoke it once, you should not see anything wrong.

What `eigenclass` means is the “instance” where you add this methods `foo` and `add_logging_to_all_methods`. By returning `self` inside the `class << self; end` block I’m getting that instance. Then I ask the block to be evaluated in the context of that instance, which does more or less the same as your previous method.

There may be an easier way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, that works beautifully... In the real code I actually regex out methods I want to wrap, so no danger of that.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply that on all classes:

```
ObjectSpace.each_object.select { |o| o.is_a? Class }.each do |klass|
  klass.class_eval do
    methods(false).each do |method|
      alias_method "old_#{method}".to_sym, method
      define_method method do |*args|
        puts "Called method: #{method}"
        send "old_#{method}", *args
      end
    end
  end rescue nil
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah nevermind, just placing the whole class << self block in the method works okay.